# Route nginx to services in different namespaces

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-controller

We have a Kubernetes cluster with an nginx controller.
We are using this nginx controller to route different paths to different services. Though,
when a service is on a different namespace, I cannot figure out how to redirect to it.

This is the nginx configuration

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: MY_BACKEND.MY_DOMAIN.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-backend
                port:
                  number: 3001

    - host: MY_FRONTEND.MY_DOMAIN.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-frontend
                port:
                  number: 3000
  ...
```

The above snippet works perfectly, but it is worth to mention that both services `my-backend` and `my-frontend` are running on `default` namespace.
We have then deployed a Jenkins instance on namespace `jenkins`. My first attempty was to simply add

```yaml
    - host: MY_JENKINS.MY_DOMAIN.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: jenkins-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Though when browsing on `MY_JENKINS.MY_DOMAIN.com` I get a 503 Service Temporary Unavailable. Could it be because it is running on a different namespace? Namely jenkins?

Normally in order to connect on different namespaces I just use the standard `service.namespace`. Though here when trying I get a standard console error/warning

`The Ingress "gateway-ingress" is invalid: spec.rules[16].http.paths[0].backend.service.name: Invalid value: "WHATEVER_VALUE_WRITTEN": a DNS-1035 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', start with an alphabetic character, and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or 'abc-123', regex used for validation is '[a-z]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?')`

I tried: service.namespace, namespace.service, namespace/service, service/namespace. All the attempts and up on the same error message.

How can I instruct nginx-controller to connect to a service that is in a specific namespace?

Answer (score 2):

You can reach a service from another namespace with: `<service>.<namespace>`; by bypassing the service you can also reach other pods by their ip address (even in another namespace).

**But** afaik all ingress controllers (also nginx) per default do not allow multi-namespace ingress out of security reasons.

For nginx you can configure ingress across multiple namespaces with a master/minion approach. You have to add the `nginx.org/mergeable-ingress-type`-annotation to your Ingress resources.

A master processes configuration on the host and minions provide the ingress resources.

Find more info here: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/cross-namespace-configuration/

And here:
https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v2.2.1/examples/mergeable-ingress-types

Comment: Thanks! I did not do the trick, and I ended up setting up the service I wanted on the same namespace. But thanks again for the tips of the documentation